# How to add description of app to app catalog for spfx solution?(not manually)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to show the description of app on app details page.Please refer image below.

This description comes form app catalog, which we can add manually but I want to keep it as deployment part as we don't have access to the app catalog.

Is there any way to add the description for spfx solution?

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to achieve this.
This the column in app catalog,there is no default value in this column.

The description which we could access in project is a property that we could show it on webpart.
[image]